# how to resolve error using Cambria font in make4ht

Tags: miktex, xetex, fontspec, tex4ht

I need to compile my .Rnw (Sweave) file into HTML, using Cambria as the default font and UTF-8 encoding so that *e.g.* Greek letters are represented correctly as characters in inline text (obviously equation mode is fine since those are embedded as image files).

Here's my "Hello, world!" tex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Then I run the command `make4ht -xu foo.tex` and document conversion fails.

Relevant bits of the log seem to be:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MikTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)

<snip, no errors or warnings...>

(<path components>\tex/generic\tex4ht\fontspec-xetex.4ht
version 2017-01-24-15:21
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fontspec_ht_scripts

l.23 ...{\typeout{use block #1}\xeunisuseblock{#1}}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Compilation fails with exit code 1.

Compiling without fontspec and using pdflatex in place of xetex works fine.  I haven't tried compiling with xetex and no fontspec.

2017 was a while ago... is it possible we just need to update our packages?  I know fontspec support was only added to tex4ht within the last few years or so.

I'm in a very restricted environment so upgrading would be difficult, though not perhaps impossible.

Comment: Yes, it is best to update your packages, versions from 2017 are quite old. If you cannot update the packages, try the `-l` option insted of `-x`, it shouldn't produce this particular error. You can also update your TeX file to not use `fontspec` with `tex4ht`, like `\ifdefined\HCode\else\usepackage{fontspec}\fi`.